# Retrieve certain row from array depending on a value

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Echo out the right row from an array compiled from a mysql database.

I have extracted information from a database (locations) containing three fields: id, name, city into an array called $array. I want to loop through another database (events) in which the id's from the first database (locations) are stored in a field. When looped I want to display the corresponding name and city from the locations database.
Is this possible without having to fetch information every loop?

This is my first try

```
$query = "Select id, name, city FROM locations WHERE typ = '1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$array[] = $row;
}
```

And then I thought I could specify the key myself like this:

```
$query = "Select id, name, city FROM locations WHERE typ = '1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$array[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to echo the right row.

Comment: When you say "databases" do you actually mean tables?

Comment: Yeah, sorry bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both tables in a single query, using something like this:

```
Select locations.id, locations.name, locations.city, events.name
FROM locations 
JOIN events ON locations.id = events.id
WHERE locations.typ = '1'
```

The `events.id` on the JOIN statement is assuming that this is the column name of the id in the `events` table. I also made the assumption that these are the two fields that will match between the two tables. Adjust accordingly if your matching criteria is different.

The `SELECT` statement was modified to pull columns from both tables. Add whichever fields are relevant to your needs.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for making me think outside my little box I've managed to trap myself in!